# Actionscript: Why do I get error when I create get x and set x in flash document class?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Message is
1024: Overriding a function that is not marked for override.

what does x and y represent for document class ? should I avoid to use x and y ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The document class represents the stage and main timeline.  It does not have an X or Y per se, but rather could be thought to supply the stage upon which all other objects derive their x and y's from.

Comment: -1. I'm afraid this is incorrect. The document class and the stage are different things. The document does have an  `x` and an `y` and you can set them. You can also declare setters for both, you just have to add the `override` keyword.

Comment: Well After spending a little time trying come up with some logic to validate my statement, I embarrassingly withdraw my answer.  I suppose I never shed the beginner's concept when moving from as2 to as3 that the document class was akin to the main timeline, which I errantly mistook for the stage. Having never had need of those methods before I suppose I never really evolved that concept further than that.  That said, I am wondering what one would use those methods for.  I would presume one would just access the x and y properties via a variable assigned to the object.

Comment: Now since my answer is clearly not correct, I don't deserve that green check mark anymore!  What to do about that?  :)

Answer (score 4):

The document class extends MovieClip or Sprite so the x and y properties are already declared and you should avoid using 'em.

They don't have any use in the document class.